# Web Service Client (Jaxb Soap Call)

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, jaxb

I don't understand why making a simple web service client became almost a science, posting soap xml somewhere and receiving result.

The goal is simple:
 - Marshalling POJO (jax-ws annotated object) into Soap XML
 - Sending Soap XML to Service endpoint
 - Receiving Soap XML response
 - Unmarshalling Soap XML into POJO

I didn't find any clean java built-in solution for that:
 - SOAPMessage doesn't handle marshalling
 - JAXB has a problem with namespaces (if not strictly defined in pojo annotations)
 - Using ws-import make enormous files for a simple call

Altough i made my own soapclient to do this (hacking a bit of SAX nodes with namespaces and prefixes upon response) and using Http(s)UrlConnection to send a request, I believe there is also some clean solution to do this (without actually having WSDL)

Any suggestions (without need of 3rd party libraries) ?

Comment: Sounds like you may be having a few issues.  XML nodes (backed by an XML schema) have two parts a local name and a namespace, so you need to provide JAXB mappings that match this.  The following post I wrote may help you out with that part:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html

Comment: The problem is that I have web services which may call another web services. The caller web service has different name space (thus having own package-info class. And I cannot tell jaxb marshaller which one to use unfortunatelly.

To be more specific:

WebService A: (namespace is http://a)
   Method AResult=AMethod(AParam)

WebService B: (namespace is http://b)
   - Create AParam pojo
   - Marshal AParam into xml using Jaxb
   - Call ServiceA.MethodA
   - Unmarshal XML into AResult